# Laravel : how to create groupBy with data outside the model run and using where claus

Tags: laravel, group-by, where-clause

I have these models below :
season :

```
public function club()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Club');
    }
```

club :

```
public function season()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Season' ,'season_id');
    }
public function league()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\League' ,'league_id');
    }
```

league :

```
public function club()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Club');
    }
```

the season have column called status which take value of 'active' or empty.

the club have column of season id.

now I want to return list of clubs grouped by league id and just those which season status is active.
I created this controller which return list of clubs in active season  :

```
public function clubs_by_active_season()
    {
        $season = Season::where('status','active')->first();
        $season_id = $season->id;
        $clubs=Club::where('season_id',$season_id)->get();

        return $clubs;
    }
```

and now I  want to make them grouped by league id ,how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rename your relationship base on relation type to help you visualize, since it has one-to-many relationship, use plural name

```php
public function clubs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Club::class);
}
```

Use `clubs()` function to build the query relationship and get the results

```php
public function clubs_by_active_season()
{
    $season = Season::where('status','active')->first();
    $clubs = $season->clubs()
        ->get() // Get the results
        ->groupBy("league_id"); // Group the collection by `league_id` key

    return $clubs;
}
```

I'm not sure if that is what you mean by "group by league_id"